# No COMPONENT named markup://lightning:recordForm found

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

While saving the lightning:recordForm tag I am getting:

> No COMPONENT named markup://lightning:recordForm found".

Am i missing amything here?

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="fieldsList" type="String[]" default="['Id', 'Name']"/>
    <lightning:recordForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
                          objectApiName="{!v.sObjectName}"
                          fields="{!v.fieldsList}"
                          columns="2"
                          mode="Edit"
                          onsuccess="{!c.myAction}"/>

</aura:component>
```

Comment: Upgrade the API version of your component.

Comment: You're on a Summer 18 org, right ?

Comment: Echoing Raul - you need v43.0 or higher to use `lightning:recordForm`